# Como controlar los MessageBox en C#

Tags: c#

Mi pregunta es como saber si ya un  `MessageBox` esta abierto para que no se abran mas del mismo mensaje??

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //panelimgop.Location = new Point(panelimgop.Location.X + -5, panelimgop.Location.Y);
        //if (panelimgop.Location.X > this.Width)
        //{
        //    panelimgop.Location = new Point(0 - panelimgop.Width, panelimgop.Location.Y);
        //}
        string optr = cboperator.Text;
        if (optr != "")
        {
            DialogResult resul = MessageBox.Show("Operator Name : " + formcs.selcopert() + " ", "Operator Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            if (resul == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
            }
            if (resul == DialogResult.No)
            {
                cboperator.Text = "";
                optr = "";
                lboperator.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es mi mensaje para abre muchas veces el mismo.

Comment: estas haciendo mas validaciones aparte de esa donde muestras otros messagebox?

Comment: Ya modifique la pregunta, el memsaje sale cada 2 minutos pero se acumulan durante cierto tiempo. Lo que deseo es que si aun no an contestado el mensaje anterios no se abra el otro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es deterner el crono mientras el MessageBox está abierto. Y ponerlo en marcha cuando se cierre el mensaje, si es necesario.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //panelimgop.Location = new Point(panelimgop.Location.X + -5, panelimgop.Location.Y);
    //if (panelimgop.Location.X > this.Width)
    //{
    //    panelimgop.Location = new Point(0 - panelimgop.Width, panelimgop.Location.Y);
    //}
    string optr = cboperator.Text;
    if (optr != "")
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        DialogResult resul = MessageBox.Show("Operator Name : " + formcs.selcopert() + " ", "Operator Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (resul == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
        }
        if (resul == DialogResult.No)
        {
            cboperator.Text = "";
            optr = "";
            lboperator.Text = "";
        }
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Otra opción sería declarar una variable:

```
private bool MsgBoxAbierto = false;
```

Y cambiarle el valor en el momento de abrir el dialogo.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //panelimgop.Location = new Point(panelimgop.Location.X + -5, panelimgop.Location.Y);
    //if (panelimgop.Location.X > this.Width)
    //{
    //    panelimgop.Location = new Point(0 - panelimgop.Width, panelimgop.Location.Y);
    //}
    string optr = cboperator.Text;
    if (optr != "" and this.MsgBoxAbierto == false)
    {
        this.MsgBoxAbierto = true;
        DialogResult resul = MessageBox.Show("Operator Name : " + formcs.selcopert() + " ", "Operator Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (resul == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
        }
        if (resul == DialogResult.No)
        {
            cboperator.Text = "";
            optr = "";
            lboperator.Text = "";
        }
        this.MsgBoxAbierto = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué no lo controlas con una variable booleana?

```
private bool isMessageBoxShown;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string optr = cboperator.Text;
    if (optr != "" && !isMessageBoxShown)
    {
        isMessageBoxShown = true;
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        DialogResult resul = MessageBox.Show("Operator Name : " + formcs.selcopert() + " ", "Operator Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        if (resul == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
        }
        if (resul == DialogResult.No)
        {
            cboperator.Text = "";
            optr = "";
            lboperator.Text = "";
        }
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        isMessageBoxShown = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: La variable booleana es para saber si hay otro mensaje abierto ?

Comment: Sí, con eso evitarías teóricamente que el MessageBox que abres en ese método no se volviera a abrir si ya lo estuviera previamente.

Comment: AAH pk, gracias